# Three-term recurrences in Orthogonal polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations, orthogonal-polynomials

hi I am reading one lecture note about Orthogonal polynomials (https://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/ICM/LecturesAndSeminars/08OctMaterials/1/Slide2.pdf)
and there's one step in the proof in "Three-term recurrence" section
about Favard's theorem I am not really catching.

[image]

can someone help explain to me how it is?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation (7) with $k-1$ instead of $k$ gives
\begin{align*}
p_{k}(\lambda)-\lambda p_{k-1}(\lambda)=-\alpha_k p_{k-1}(\lambda)-\gamma_{k-1} p_{k-2}(\lambda)
+\sum_{j=0}^{k-3}\delta_j p_j(\lambda)\tag{$7^{\prime}$}
\end{align*}
Taking the inner product of equation ($7^{\prime}$) with $p_k$ from the left gives
\begin{align*}
\langle  p_k,p_k\rangle-\langle p_k, \lambda p_{k-1}\rangle=0\tag{$7^{\prime\prime}$}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from ($7^{\prime\prime}$) and the definition of the inner product (see formula (3) in OP's referred link):
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\langle\lambda p_k,p_{k-1}\rangle}
> &=\int_{a}^b\left(\lambda p_k(\lambda)\right)p_{k-1}(\lambda)\,d\alpha(\lambda)\\
> &=\int_{a}^bp_{k}(\lambda)\left(\lambda p_{k-1}(\lambda)\right)\,d\alpha(\lambda)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\langle p_k,\lambda p_{k-1}\rangle}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\langle  p_{k},p_k\rangle}
> \end{align*}
> according to the claim.